# Krull dimension of localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

If $R$ is a commutative ring and $m$ a maximal ideal therein, then what are the conditions for the Krull dimension of $R$ equaling to the Krull dimension of $R_m$?

Comment: Since prime ideals of $R_m$ are in inclusion-preserving bijection with prime ideals of $R$ contained in $m$, the statement that $R_m$ has the same Krull dimension as $R$ is equivalent to the statement that $m$ is of maximal height in $R$. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161937/what-conditions-guarantee-that-all-maximal-ideals-have-the-same-height) for a related discussion and some sufficient conditions.

Comment: It should be pointed out that in nice situations (e.g. $R$ is a fintitely generated $k$-algebra), then all maximal ideals have the same height, so this is true for all $m$.